# Getting a specific Column value from selected row in a tree.view setup using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, tree

I have an inventory program I am writing and I need to get a specific column's data from the focused row selected by the user.

```
def ShowChangeForm():
    curitem = tree.focus()
    print tree.item(curitem)
```

Below is the current out put of the above code

> {'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': [**12**, u'123 auberndale', 1234,
>   u'0.0', 1022018, u'Air Mover', u'Phoenix', 1234], 'open': 0, 'tags':
>   ''}

My tree code is below

```
def ViewForm():
    global tree
    TopViewForm = Frame(Home, width=600, bd=1, relief=SOLID)
    TopViewForm.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    LeftViewForm = Frame(Home, width=600)
    LeftViewForm.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    MidViewForm = Frame(Home, width=1000)
    MidViewForm.pack(fill=X)
    lbl_text = Label(TopViewForm, text="View Products", font=('arial', 18), width=600)
    lbl_text.pack(fill=X)
    lbl_txtsearch = Label(LeftViewForm, text="Search", font=('arial', 15))
    lbl_txtsearch.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
    search = Entry(LeftViewForm, textvariable=SEARCH, font=('arial', 15), width=10)
    search.pack(side=TOP,  padx=10, fill=X)
    btn_search = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Search", command=Search)
    btn_search.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
    btn_reset = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Reset", command=Reset)
    btn_reset.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
    btn_delete = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Delete", command=Delete)
    btn_delete.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
    scrollbarx = Scrollbar(MidViewForm, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrollbary = Scrollbar(MidViewForm, orient=VERTICAL)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(MidViewForm, columns=("Product ID", "Location", "Equipment #", "Price Per Day", "DatePlaced", "Type", "Make", "Model", "Total"), selectmode="extended", height=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
    scrollbary.config(command=tree.yview)
    scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    scrollbarx.config(command=tree.xview)
    scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    tree.heading('Product ID', text="Product ID",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Location', text="Location",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('DatePlaced', text="DatePlaced",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Equipment #', text="Equipment #",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Type', text="Type",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Price Per Day', text="Price Per Day",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Make', text="Make",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Model', text="Model",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Total', text="Total",anchor=W)
    tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
    tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
    tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.column('#4', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.column('#5', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.column('#6', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.column('#7', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.column('#8', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.column('#9', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    tree.pack(fill=X)
    DisplayData()
```

What is needed is the first row of the selected column( In list of values, in bold above value "**12**" to be assigned to a variable that can be passed to another function. How do I get the selected row but first column value only and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
print tree.item(curitem)['values'][0]
```

The data is in json format, you could use python dictionary to access it.

Comment: Perfect solution Thank you!